# Passing a LPDWORD as out parameter

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I need to create a function with this structure:

```
BOOL myfunc(LPDWORD myLpdword){ // myLpdword must be an out parameter

    DWORD myDword = 1;
    myLpdword = &myDword;
    return true;

}

int main(){

    DWORD outDword = 20;
    myfunc(&outDword);
    cout << outDword << end1;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that the value of outDword would be 1 (changed by myfunc), but the value is not changed by myfunc.
Please, can you give me a hint to solve this problem?

Comment: These are the basics taught in every book (although it's rather more C than C++). I strongly suggest at least learning the basics of C++ before doing Windows API stuff.

Comment: You are making an imperfect attempt to return the address of a local variable.  That's undefined behavior, the variable no longer exists after the function returns.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this

```
BOOL myfunc(LPDWORD myLpdword){ // myLpdword must be an out parameter
    *myLpdword = 1;
    return true;

}
```

`Out parameter` is not something that means anything in C++. MS use it but only because they are using a consistent terminology across different languages.

In C++ terms what you did is pass a *pointer* to the variable you want to modify to `myfunc`. What the above code does is take that pointer and *dereference* with the `*` operator it to modify the variable you wanted modified.

I like that you're writing small test programs to check your understanding of C++. But as others said there's no real substitute for a decent book. Any C++ book is going to cover this.

Answer (score 0):

You passed in a pointer to outDword.

myLpdword is now a pointer to outDword.

You then changed myLpdword to be a pointer to myDword.

You never did anything with the ***VALUE*** of outDword.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ this is called pass-by-reference. You denote it with an ampersand in the function signature:

```
bool myfunc(DWORD &myDword) {…
```

The ampersands you are using now are actually getting the address of the variables, so you should remove those.

Comment: One small change: `LPDWORD` should be `DWORD`. `LP` (nowadays) means pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You assigned the pointer of a variable that will not exist after exiting the function body (read on scopes in C/C++.

To solve your problem, assign the value of the variable to the dereferenced pointer, like so: `*myLpdword = myDword;`. It would also be wise to check that the value of the pointer is not null before dereferencing it like this: `if (myLpdword == 0) { return; }` . This check doesn't guarantee that the pointer is safe to assign to, but Atleast guards you against null pointer access.